# Angular signalr issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working on a demo project where in an Angular project, I am calling a component called signal.component via app.component in loop and the objective of signal component is to establish connection ,get connection id via backend made in asp.net core and display the same.

As I am increasing the number of iteration to call signal.component to implement establishing concurrent, I am getting the error in the console of the browser. The screenshot of the error is attached.

The other issue is that as I increase the number of iteration, the count of connection Id's is not appropriate.

Below is the angular code for signal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { SignalViewModel } from '../models/signal-view-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signal',
  templateUrl: './signal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signal.component.css']
})
export class SignalComponent implements OnInit {

  connectionId: number;
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  constructor() {
    this.buildConnection();
    this.startConnection();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public buildConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:61961/demo").build();
  }

  public startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {

      this.hubConnection.invoke("getConnectionId").then((connectionId) => {
        console.log(connectionId, " connection Id");
        this.connectionId = connectionId;
       
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('eror while starting the connection', err);

      setTimeout(function () { this.startConnection(); }, 3000);
    });

  }

}
```

The above component will display the connectionId in template file which will be iterated by app.component to create concurrent connections.

Below is the code of hub in .net core.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRDemo.Hubs
{
    public class DemoHub : Hub
    {
        private List<Mod> modList;

        private readonly IHubContext<DemoHub> _hubContext;

        public DemoHub(IHubContext<DemoHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public void GetData(string connectionId)
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("messageData", "message " + connectionId);
        }



        public string GetConnectionId()
        {
            return Context.ConnectionId; 
        }

    }
}
```

The below code is of Startup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using SignalRDemo.Hubs;

namespace SignalRDemo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
            //.AddJsonProtocol();

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
             {
                 builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

             }));


            //services.AddSingleton<Demo>();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<DemoHub>("/demo");
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly refer to the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nVX9.jpg) of the error generated in browser.

Comment: I cannot see any error screenshot as you mentioned. Can you please check and share the error screenshot ?

Comment: I have added the link of the screenshot in the question. Kindly now check the question.

Comment: Can you share also startup.cs

Comment: @pc_coder I have updated the question and added the code of startup.cs file as well.